# Como fazer botão ficar com outra cor ao ser clicado e selecionado

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como posso usar javascript para fazer alteração da cor do botão após ele ter sido clicado; ou seja, abaixo no código tem 2 formatos. Caso clique no formato A1, o botão onde está a div mudará de cor e ficará com a cor alterada indicando que o formato esta selecionado; aí, caso clique no outro botão, desativará o A1 e ativará a cor no A2. Como posso fazer isso usando javascript, sendo que isso deve ser feito com múltiplos itens?

```html
<div onclick="document.getElementById('A1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('A2').style.display='none';">Formato 1</div><div onclick="document.getElementById('A1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('A2').style.display='none';">Formato 2</div>

<div id="A1" style="display:block;">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
<div id="A2" style="display:none;">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
```

Pois bem obrigada pela solução com o código abaixo mais agora só para finalizar como posso fazer o código abaixo funcionar com vários itens ao mesmo tempo pois preciso que ele funcione com vários itens na mesma pagina.

```html
<div>Item 1</div>
<div id="formato1">Formato 1</div>
<div id="formato2">Formato 2</div>

<div id="A1" style="display:block;">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
<div id="A2" style="display:none;">Conteudo oculto 2</div>


<div>Item 2</div>
<div id="formato1">Formato 1</div>
<div id="formato2">Formato 2</div>

<div id="A1" style="display:block;">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
<div id="A2" style="display:none;">Conteudo oculto 2</div>


<div>Item 3</div>
<div id="formato1">Formato 1</div>
<div id="formato2">Formato 2</div>

<div id="A1" style="display:block;">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
<div id="A2" style="display:none;">Conteudo oculto 2</div>
```

Comment: Tem como você colocar um exemplo em um plunkr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Item 1</legend>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="001">Formato 1</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="002">Formato 2</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="003">Formato 3</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="004">Formato 4</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="005">Formato 5</div>
    <div class="atb" data-tab="006">Formato 6</div>

    <div class="content hide" data-tab="001">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="002">Conteudo oculto 2</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="003">Conteudo oculto 3</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="004">Conteudo oculto 4</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="005">Conteudo oculto 5</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="006">Conteudo oculto 6</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Item 2</legend>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="001">Formato 1</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="002">Formato 2</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="003">Formato 3</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="004">Formato 4</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="005">Formato 5</div>
    <div class="atb" data-tab="006">Formato 6</div>

    <div class="content hide" data-tab="001">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="002">Conteudo oculto 2</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="003">Conteudo oculto 3</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="004">Conteudo oculto 4</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="005">Conteudo oculto 5</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="006">Conteudo oculto 6</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Item 3</legend>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="001">Formato 1</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="002">Formato 2</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="003">Formato 3</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="004">Formato 4</div>
    <div class="tab" data-tab="005">Formato 5</div>
    <div class="atb" data-tab="006">Formato 6</div>

    <div class="content hide" data-tab="001">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="002">Conteudo oculto 2</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="003">Conteudo oculto 3</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="004">Conteudo oculto 4</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="005">Conteudo oculto 5</div>
    <div class="content hide" data-tab="006">Conteudo oculto 6</div>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
.focus {
   color: blue;
}    
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
var todasTabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

function onTabClick () {
    var tab = this;
    var tabs = tab.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('tab');
    var contents = tab.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('content');

    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (tab.dataset.tab == tabs[i].dataset.tab) {
            tabs[i].classList.add('focus');
        } else {
            tabs[i].classList.remove('focus');
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
        if (tab.dataset.tab == contents[i].dataset.tab) {
            contents[i].classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
            contents[i].classList.add('hide');
        }
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < todasTabs.length; i++) {
    todasTabs[i].onclick = onTabClick;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/a4z2u17t/5/

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria obrigada

Comment: Esqueci de falar que no caso são 6 itens e tentei alterar o código e deu erro.

Comment: alterando o exemplo.

Comment: pronto, olha agora

Comment: Grato pela melhorias no código obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode mudar a cor adicionando uma classe ao elemento clicado. No exemplo abaixo, existe no css uma classe `.sel` que muda a cor do elemento para vermelho.

```js
// uma função "helper" somente para não precisar ficar digitando "document.getElementById" toda hora
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

// só será executado depois que o DOM estiver completamente carregado
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
     function formatosClick() {
        for(var i = 0; i < conteudos.length; i++) {
            // esconde todas as divs de conteúdo
            conteudos[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < formatos.length; i++) {
            // "desmarca" todas as divs de formato
            formatos[i].classList.remove('sel');
        }
        // pega o ID da div de conteúdo do atributo "data-item-id"
        $(this.getAttribute('data-item-id')).style.display = 'block';

        // "marca" o item atual com a classe 'sel'
        this.classList.add('sel');
    }
    
    // pega todos as divs com a classe 'formato' da página
    var formatos = document.getElementsByClassName('formato');
    // pega todas as divs com a classe 'conteúdo' da página
    var conteudos = document.getElementsByClassName('conteudo');
    
    // percorre o array formatos e adiciona a função que 
    // será executada no evento onclick de todos eles (formatosClick)
    for(var i = 0; i < formatos.length; i++) {
        formatos[i].onclick = formatosClick;
    }
});
```

```css
.sel {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="formato" data-item-id="A1">Formato 1</div>
<div class="formato" data-item-id="A2">Formato 2</div>
<div class="formato" data-item-id="A3">Formato 3</div>
<div class="formato" data-item-id="A4">Formato 4</div>

<div id="A1" class="conteudo" style="display:block;">Conteudo oculto 1</div>
<div id="A2" class="conteudo" style="display:none;">Conteudo oculto 2</div>
<div id="A3" class="conteudo" style="display:none;">Conteudo oculto 3</div>
<div id="A4" class="conteudo" style="display:none;">Conteudo oculto 4</div>
```

Para adicionar mais itens basta ajustar o atributo `data-item-id` para bater com o ID da div de conteúdo que você quer exibir.

Comment: Acho que fiz algo errado veja abaixo o código não esta funcionando.

Comment: @Rodrigo Não funcionou porque você está executando o javascript antes do documento terminar de carregar. [Veja no Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C7BVbB890NxKGeW0RLjr?p=preview) um exemplo funcionando com `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"...)`

Comment: Ata obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: @Rodrigo Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita caso ela tenha resolvido seu problema.

Comment: Falta agora somente fazer aparecer ele funcionar de forma múltipla como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: @Rodrigo Atualizei minha resposta. Não tinha reparado nesse detalhe que você ia usar mais elementos além desses dois. Nesse novo código você pode ir adicionando itens e ajustando os valores infinitamente.

Comment: Grato pela ajuda estarei a usar seu código também.